# Drag and Drop operation in HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

Drag and Drop operation requires to set up a function that specifies what data is to be dragged, for instance:

HTML code:

```
<img id="drag1" src="img_logo.gif" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag_start(event)" width="336" height="69">
```

Javascript code:

```
function drag_start(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}
```

It's not to clear to me if the first parameter of the setData method should be `"text"` or `"text/plan"` (or something else).

The example [here](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_draganddrop.asp) uses `"text"`, but the example [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API) uses `"text/plain"` and other types.

Comment: It can be whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

It can be whatever you want. For example, in my code, I have

```
domItem.ondragstart = event => {
            event.dataTransfer.setData("itemid", this.id);
        };
```

and then, on the drag target, I have

```
domBox.ondrop = ev => {
            if (!ev.dataTransfer.getData('itemid')) return;
            ev.preventDefault();
            var itemId = ev.dataTransfer.getData("itemid");
            // do stuff with itemid
        };
```

Comment: _The DataTransfer.setData() method sets the drag operation's drag data to the specified data and type_ according to these specifications: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer/setData

Comment: @BlueSkies nothing on that page, as far as I can see, actually limits the value you can put into the first argument. It has to be a string, according to that documentation, but there are not other requirements. It suggests `text/plain` and `text/uri-list`, but you can test it for yourself in a variety of browsers, it will let you put in any string you like and still work perfectly well..